# Ctrl + Click on a Firefox tab places a * on it. What does this signify?

Tags: firefox

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on a Firefox tab, the display in the tab includes an asterisk (*) before the page name.

What does this signify? Does this have any special significance?

Comment: I don't see it. Are you sure no extensions are involved?

Comment: I have Tab-Mix Plus installed. (As suggested in the Answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is part of the [Tab Mix Plus](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) extension.

The default defined action for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> is `Selects the tab for merging`. You can then merge tabs into one window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. Tabs selected for merging are indicated with a `(*)` before the page name (that's an asterisk enclosed in parentheses).

Editor's note: The shortcut used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, but that now opens a firefox dev tool. After extensive online searching for the new shortcut, I had to search the source code of the extension.

[[image: Screenshot of Tab Mix Plus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> options]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiS0N.png)

Comment: I never realized Tab-mix plus had such an option. Thank you for the help.

Comment: For me, on recent FireFox, Ctrl+Shift+M opens the "mobile view".  I'm honestly not sure how to cause the merge to happen, given that that shortcut is not available... I don't see any right-click menu option.